# Checking time since last key was pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a script that requires the ability to redirect someone if a key has not been pressed within 15 seconds, the only problem is I don't know how to check how much time has lapsed since the last key was pressed.

I am aware of keyboard events but they wait for input instead of checking when last input was received.

Comment: Add an event listener to the keypress event, store the time that happened somewhere (I've used localstorage as it can be used crosstab if on the same domain) then use `setInterval` to check that time against the time now.

Comment: You could also just do the dirty variant and do a simple `setTimeout(()=>{}, 15000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="input">
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="lastKeyPressTime">
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function inactivitiy(){
        var lastTime = $('#lastKeyPressTime').val();
        lastTime++;
        $('#lastKeyPressTime').val(lastTime);
        if(lastTime>15){
            //alert('time to redirect !');
            window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            inactivitiy();
        }, 1000);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input').on('keypress', function(){
            $('#lastKeyPressTime').val(0);
        });

        inactivitiy();

    });
</script>
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I like this answer, but it is a bit over engineered

Comment: Not at all, i use inputs with type hidden all the time, they make things much easier ^^

Comment: Brilliant, all the answers are good but I understand this one the most. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: There is no reason to use a hidden input at all, all would do is effect the performance negatively as it has to read and right to the DOM. Why would you not just use a variable?

Answer (score 4):

This is rather simple implementation, but should offer you guidelines on how to build your own:

```js
let timeout;
const handleKeyUp = (ev) => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => { location.href = '//google.com' }, 15e3);
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
```

Comment: This is good, do we also need to check if `timeout` has a value before clearing it or the internals take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let timeout;
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => console.log(e.key), 1500) 
  // 1.5 sec so you can see the effect quicker
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```